# Optimize algorithm arrange an array with items with even-indexs are on left side of array, items with odd-indexs are on right side of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

Requirement: using recursion, size of array is an even number.

For example:

0...1...2...3...4...5 (order of index)

a...b...c...d...e...f (array before arrange)

a...c...e...b...d...f (array after arrange)

---

0......1......2......3......4......5......6......7 (order of index)

a1....b1....a2....b2....a3....b3....a4....b4 (array before arrange)

a1....a2....a3....a4....b1....b2....b3....b4 (array after arrange)

---

The problem looks easy to solve if we dont care about optimization, we can use temp array or use recursion combine with a loop to shift items ... I think this way is not best solution ....I try to use recursion combine with swap operation, without using loop ... but I fail.

Hope someone suggests me an idea to resolve the problem, thanks any help

Answer (score 0):

First, let me mention that the optimum solution depends on the size of the array (how many elements are occupied) assuming this in in memory which means the array size is constrained, you could get away with a quick loop for a complexity of O(n) like so. Let array be N, and the count of elements in N is x.

- Get the starting index of all odd elements = x/2 (if x is even) or
  (x + 1)/2
- let that index be a
- let even elements start at b. let b = 0
- create output array called T
- while start = 0 but less than x, INCR and BEGIN
- if start is even, place element at N(start) into T(b++)
- if start is odd, place element at N(start) into T(a++)

array insertions and lookups are accepted O(1).

**Operations are**

1. Determine current index, you cannot avoid checking every index in the array.
2. You cannot avoid generating output, but its more computationally expensive to delete an element, retrieve a value, and place it at the correct position. Easier to just insert in an already allocated space in memory.

You do have the option of running concurrent for loops which would speed things up a bit, but I imagine that is beyond what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think the optimum solution would be with a recursion, but if it's part of the problem description, and if I had the guarantee that the size of the array is a power of 2, then I would apply divide and conquer.

The simple case would be when the size of the problem is 2. That problem is already solved. After solving 2 partitions of size 2, you have to combine them in a partition of size 4. eg.

0......1......2......3......4......5......6......7 (order of index)

a1....b1....a2....b2....a3....b3....a4....b4 (array before arrange)

a1....a2....b1....b2....a3....a4....b3....b4 (array after combining partitions of size 2)

After you finish combining partitions of size 2, you combine the partitions of size 4.

a1....a2....a3....a4....b1....b2....b3....b4 (array after combining partitions of size 2)

Combining 2 partitions of size N, means swapping the N/2 items in the right of the left partition, with N/2 items on the left of the right partition. That can be done with a simple loop.

Hope this thoughts help you with your task.